# Insert Data with JavaScript (SAP HANA Express 2.0)

Tags: javascript, html, hana

I'm learning SAP at the moment and I have some "newbie" issues with HANA DB.

I would like to insert data to some database (with Javascript / HTML5-App) but I can't find a tutorial.

I use SAP HANA Express 2.0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 easy ways to do this, first you can build an SAP HANA [xsa](/questions/tagged/xsa) application using the WebIDE and there are [extensive tutorials for that](https://www.sap.com/developer/groups/hana-xsa-get-started.html) or you can use the Node based library.

You can also use a combination of the both by creating a micro-service in XSA that is called by your HTML5 application.

For just straight JavaScript/HTML5 - I have a sample shell in [Github](https://github.com/SAP/hxe-google-app-engine-shell) that could be a good starting point. It is Node JS based.

The main parts though are including the [hdb](/questions/tagged/hdb) library

`var hdb = require('hdb');`

Then making the insert statement to the table and passing the connection object.

```
var sql = 'insert into MYTABLE values(1,'mydata');
client.exec(sql, cb);
```